# Bash script: infinite loop execution doesn't work

Tags: shell, unix

Hi my code only run once then stops. I want it to be infinite. Please help.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
    do
    read -p "make a choice (order/quit) " order
    case $order in
        order )    break;;
        quit )     exit;;
        * ) echo "is not a valid."; exec bash "$0";
    esac
done
       read -p " your name :  " name
       read -p "your telephone?  " phone

printf "======================================================\n"

echo Hello $name:

printf "======================================================\n"

echo Your telephone is $phone
```

Comment: Why on earth do you have the `exec bash "$@";` after the error reporting?  (Errors should go to standard error, too; use `>&2` to redirect the standard output of `echo` to standard error.)  You've no loop around the name, phone prompting and echoing, so if you want an indefinite number of iterations, you'll need to add a loop (an infinite loop) around the whole script.

Comment: I am a proper beginner sorry, I thought the while loop was an infinite one. I would really appreciate it if you could please show me how the code should be.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You've no loop around the name, phone prompting and echoing, so if you want an indefinite number of iterations, you'll need to add a loop (an infinite loop) around the whole script.  You should report errors to standard error (that's the `>&2` in the code below).  And the `exec bash "$@"` is an unusual and unnecessary way to do things, though it probably works (but it makes the inner `while` loop below redundant).

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    while true
    do
        read -p "Make a choice (order/quit) " order
        case $order in
        (order) break;;
        (quit)  exit;;
        (*)     echo "$order is not a valid." >&2;;
        esac
    done

    read -p "Your name?  " name
    read -p "Your phone? " phone
    printf "======================================================\n"
    echo Hello $name:
    printf "======================================================\n"
    echo Your telephone is $phone
done
```